# Insert Data Into a Table Using Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table

I have these two tables

**daily_info**

| date | id | name | place |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-11 | 1 | Jhon | null |
| 2022-04-12 | 1 | Jhon | null |
| 2022-04-13 | 1 | Jhon | null |
| 2022-04-14 | 1 | Jhon | null |
| 2022-04-15 | 1 | Jhon | null |
| 2022-04-16 | 1 | Jhon | null |

**change_values**

| date | id | change_col | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-14 | 1 | place | Chicago |
| 2022-04-16 | 1 | place | India |
| 2022-04-16 | 1 | name | John watts |

From these two tables, I want to create a new table that will look like this

**Desire Output**

**history_table**

| date | id | name | place |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-11 | 1 | Jhon | null |
| 2022-04-12 | 1 | Jhon | null |
| 2022-04-13 | 1 | Jhon | null |
| 2022-04-14 | 1 | Jhon | Chicago |
| 2022-04-15 | 1 | Jhon | Chicago |
| 2022-04-16 | 1 | Jhon Watts | India |

So far I could only join these two tables and try to use the **case-when** clause, I know I need to use lag but I am not sure how

**My code**

```
Select id, 
    date,
    (Case When change_col = 'place' Then new_value End) As place,
    (Case When change_col = 'name' Then new_value End) As name
From daily_info
Left Join change_values On d.id = c.id And d.date = c.date
```

Comment: You really need to fix your design; you have denormalised data. Never store delimited data in your table. If you need a *n*-to-many relationship you need multiple tables. It also looks like you're mixing relational and EAV designs, which will make things harder still.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have edited my question. My table don't have this type of value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join (apply) you change table based on the date, once for each change type.

```
declare @daily_info table ([date] date, id int, [name] varchar(32), place varchar(32));

insert into @daily_info ([date], id, [name], place)
values
('2022-04-11', 1, 'Jhon', null),
('2022-04-12', 1, 'Jhon', null),
('2022-04-13', 1, 'Jhon', null),
('2022-04-14', 1, 'Jhon', null),
('2022-04-15', 1, 'Jhon', null),
('2022-04-16', 1, 'Jhon', null);

declare @change_values table ([date] date, id int, change_col varchar(32), new_value varchar(32));

insert into @change_values ([date], id, change_col, new_value)
values
('2022-04-14', 1, 'place', 'Chicago'),
('2022-04-16', 1, 'place', 'India'),
('2022-04-16', 1, 'name',  'John,Dan');

select DI.[date], DI.id
    , coalesce(CV2.new_value, DI.[name]) [name]
    , coalesce(CV1.new_value, DI.place) place
from @daily_info DI
outer apply (
    select top 1 change_col, new_value
    from @change_values CV
    where CV.[date] <= DI.[date] and change_col = 'place'
    order by [date] desc
) CV1
outer apply (
    select top 1 change_col, new_value
    from @change_values CV
    where CV.[date] <= DI.[date] and change_col = 'name'
    order by [date] desc
) CV2;
```

Returns:

| date | id | name | place |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-11 | 1 | Jhon | NULL |
| 2022-04-12 | 1 | Jhon | NULL |
| 2022-04-13 | 1 | Jhon | NULL |
| 2022-04-14 | 1 | Jhon | Chicago |
| 2022-04-15 | 1 | Jhon | Chicago |
| 2022-04-16 | 1 | John,Dan | India |

Comment: Hello; The name value of the last row should be 'John Watts' and not 'John,Dan'.

Comment: it's ok - it's the value that you've but in your change_values table. I thought that you were doing a STRING_AGG or something like that.

Comment: @Kendle OP edited question after I answered.